# Creating a Type with a minimal set of properties

Tags: typescript

I would like to create the type `Foo` with as minimal properties needed `blah`
by instance :

```
interface Foo {
    blah: string;
}

f: Foo = {blah: "lol"}
```

What I want though, is that an error is mentioned if the property `blah` isn't 
specified but also that an error isn't mentioned if a `Foo` has more properties than `blah`

```
f: Foo = {boo: "lol"} // property blah is missing

f: Foo = {blah: "lol", boo: "lol"} // this is fine
```

So to sum it up, having the properties I mention in my interface, as a minimal set of properties.

How can I achieve that (it doesn't work with my `Foo` interface as mentioned above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this do:

```
interface Foo {
    blah: string;
    [name: string]: string;
}

let f1: Foo = {boo: "lol"} // error
let f2: Foo = {blah: "lol", boo: "lol"} // fine
```

Comment: So If I got this right, you specify that indexing the object with a string is basically allowed

Comment: Yes. Because you want to have more (unknown) properties to `Foo` instances other than `blah`. Since they are not known in advance you need to use indexing.